# Keeping a range within a certain set of numbers

Tags: java

For my Java class, I am writing a small program that first picks a `int` number between 1 and 100.  It then prompts a user to start guessing for the correct `int`.  If the user guesses too high or too low of an `int`, the program prints out a new range for them to guess within.  If the user enters a `String` or a `double`, the program simply re-asks the user to input an `int`, but without changing the range in any way.

A sample output (when secret number is 20) would look like:

```
c:\csc116> java GuessingGame 
Guess the secret number!
Enter a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive): 45
Enter a number between 1 and 44 (inclusive): jlkj
Enter a number between 1 and 44 (inclusive): 31.0  //double
Enter a number between 1 and 44 (inclusive): 1000 //outside the range of 1-100
Enter a number between 1 and 44 (inclusive): 34
Enter a number between 1 and 33 (inclusive): 15
Enter a number between 16 and 33 (inclusive): 20    
You win!
```

The program appears to be almost there, but with one exception.  One of the requirements is that when a user types an `int` that is outside our given range of 1 and 100, the print out message does not change (as seen in example above).  This is where I am getting stumped quite a bit, and am looking to see if anyone can help guide me to the correct answer.

```
import java.util.*;


public class GuessingGame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        introduction();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int guess = 0;
        int minimum = 1;
        int maximum = 100;
        int secretNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

        System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
        while (guess != secretNumber) {
            if (console.hasNextInt()) {
                guess = console.nextInt();
                if (guess > secretNumber) {
                    maximum = guess - 1;
                    System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
                }
                if (guess < secretNumber) {
                    minimum =guess + 1;
                    System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
                }
                if (guess == secretNumber) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                }
            } else {
                console.next();
                System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void introduction() {
        System.out.println("Guess the secret number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the print out message does not change"? It printed "Enter a number between 1 and 44 (inclusive):" both before and after you entered your out of range number. It looks the same to me.

Comment: Meaning that if initially the printout is "Enter a number between 1 and 100", and a user first types in 4, the next print out would be "Enter a number between 5 and 100".  But if the user were then to enter 1000, instead of an int between 1 and 100, the next print out would still read "Enter a number between 5 and 100", not "Enter a number between 5 and 999".  Hopefully this gives clarity...I have trouble explaining myself at times.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I mistook your sample output for your actual output.

Comment: It is because the logic is not correct.  If the user enters anything other than 1 .. 100, it is caught by the 'else'.  You want to check to see if the input is valid.  BTW, if this is homework, please mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for not tagging as HW.  Should that go in the title?  As for the else statement, I believe that only catches doubles and strings.  But currently, any integer (whether in or outside of the 1...100 range is captured.

Comment: @CKuharski I don't see much point in marking posts as homework. Whether or not its homework is irrelevant as long as it is a clear question that shows at least some attempt at trying.

Comment: @Jason C - It has to do with how to answer the question i.e. leaving room for the student to work out the implementation VS copy-n-paste. I've also noticed other making a the same request and they seem reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
            guess = console.nextInt();
            if (guess > secretNumber) {
                maximum = guess - 1;
                System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
            }
            if (guess < secretNumber) {
                minimum =guess + 1;
                System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
            }
            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
```

Right now you are not checking for min/max range at all. You will have to add an explicit check for that, but the caveat (missed in the other answers here) is that you have to make sure you *don't* process the input as a guess if it is out of range. Your current style of using `if`s without `else`s means you have to be careful when you implement it. You have a few options, e.g.:

```
            guess = console.nextInt();
            if (guess < minimumAllowed || guess > maximumAllowed) {
                // handle error
            } else {
                // handle valid input
                if (guess > secretNumber) {        
                    // ...
                }
                if (guess < secretNumber) {
                    // ...
                }
                if (guess == secretNumber) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
```

Or:

```
            guess = console.nextInt();
            if (guess < minimumAllowed || guess > maximumAllowed) {
                // handle error
            } else if (guess > secretNumber) {        
                // ...
            } else if (guess < secretNumber) {
                // ...
            } else if (guess == secretNumber) {
                // ...
            }
```

Or, sticking with your current style, as long as you don't have to do any more unrelated logic in the loop (which seems to be the case in your program):

```
            guess = console.nextInt();
            if (guess < minimumAllowed || guess > maximumAllowed) {
                // handle error
                continue;
            }
            // handle valid input
            if (guess > secretNumber) {        
                // ...
            }
            if (guess < secretNumber) {
                // ...
            }
            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                // ...
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you additionally want to hint the user to the original minimum and maximum, you should keep these two values separately and insert another `if`-check at the start of the loop like

```
guess = console.nextInt();
if (guess > originalMaximum) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number less then " + originalMaximum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking the guessed number relative to the secret number.  What you are missing is a check of the guessed number relative to the maximum and minimum.  For example:

```
if (guess > maximum) {
    System.out.print("Too high!");
} else if (guess < minimum) {
    System.out.print("Too low!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you check if the guessed number is less or more than the secret number, place this check just before:

```
if (guess < minimum || guess > maximum) 
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum);
    continue;
}

if (guess > secretNumber) 
{
   maximum = guess - 1;
   System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + " (inclusive): ");
}
```

Comment: +1 for making the point about skipping the `secretNumber` checks.